# Can't get children multiply values using XMLTABLE

Tags: xml-parsing, db2, multiple-columns, xmltable

guys, i'm trying to get values from the next query

```
SELECT X.val, X.tdate
  FROM 
  XMLTABLE ('$d/IRR' passing XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<IRR><value>2</value><tdate>2014-06-05</tdate><value>4</value><tdate>2014-08-05</tdate></IRR>') as "d" 
    COLUMNS 
    val      DOUBLE  PATH './value',
    tdate     DATE   PATH './tdate' ) AS X;
```

but I always get the error:

> An expression of data type "( item(), item()+ )" cannot be used when
>   the data type "DATE" is expected in the context

at the same time everything works fine if there is only one value and date like

```
SELECT X.val, X.tdate
  FROM 
  XMLTABLE ('$d/IRR' passing XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<IRR><value>2</value><tdate>2014-06-05</tdate></IRR>') as "d" 
    COLUMNS 
    val      DOUBLE  PATH './value',
    tdate     DATE   PATH './tdate' ) AS X;
```

And as I understand here it's because XMLTABLE waits only for 1 value and it cann't parse the doc if there are few of them
What's more it works fine if there is only 1 column need to be returned like this even though there are a few values:

```
SELECT  X.tdate
  FROM 
  XMLTABLE ('$d/IRR/tdate' passing XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<IRR><value>2</value><tdate>2014-06-05</tdate><value>4</value><tdate>2014-08-05</tdate></IRR>') as "d" 
    COLUMNS 
    tdate     DATE   PATH '.' ) AS X;
```

So this query returns both dates.

```
tdate
2014-06-05
2014-08-05
```

So is there any way to return both columns with multiply values in the same query?
e.g.

```
val  tdate
2    2014-06-05
4    2014-08-05
```

Note: that is the representation of the xml document which is passed in my procedure (it could contain more than 2 values)

> `<IRR><value>2</value><tdate>2014-06-05</tdate><value>4</value><tdate>2014-08-05</tdate></IRR>`

Answer (score 0):

`XMLTABLE()` can return a special ordinality column, containing the sequential number of each row. You can use it to do something like:

```
WITH t(x) AS (VALUES XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<IRR><value>2</value><tdate>2014-06-05</tdate><value>4</value><tdate>2014-08-05</tdate></IRR>')) 
SELECT x1.value, x2.tdate 
FROM 
  t, 
  XMLTABLE ('$X//value'  
    COLUMNS 
    value       INT    PATH '.',
    idx         FOR ORDINALITY) AS X1,
  XMLTABLE ('$X//tdate'  
    COLUMNS 
    tdate       DATE    PATH '.',
    idx         FOR ORDINALITY) AS X2
WHERE x1.idx = x2.idx
ORDER BY 2
```

This assumes that the XML parser preserves the element order, which, although not explicitly documented, seems to be the case with all parsers I've worked with.

Ideally you should rethink your XML schema, for example, passing `tdate` as an attribute of `value` (or vice versa).